# How to extract XPath with PHP cURL

Tags: curl

I try to extract some information with curl command.
Using developer tools chrome extract and copy the elements:

outerHTML

```
<span id="our_price_display" class="" itemprop="price" content="43.35">43,35 €</span>
```

selector

```
#our_price_display
```

XPath

```
//*[@id="our_price_display"]
```

I would like to extract the **content** value (43.35)

How can extract the price via cURL or combined with php-cli's DOMDocument + DOMXPath?

I use for example this url: https://www.primor.eu/valentino/39683-valentino-uomo-intense-edp.html#/volumen-edp_50_ml_vapo

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [php](/questions/tagged/php) and [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

```php
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('https://www.primor.eu/valentino/39683-valentino-uomo-intense-edp.html#/volumen-edp_50_ml_vapo');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->query('//span[@id="our_price_display"]/text()');

header("Content-type: text/plain");

foreach ($nodes as $i => $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue, "\n";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) and [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) :

```
xidel -se '//span[@id="our_price_display"]/text()' 'https://domain.tld/query_s'
```

### Output:

```
43,35 €
```

Comment: sounds good but there's any way to use another command? I running a SO win ARM processor and can't find version for that architecture.

Comment: Did you see my other answer with php ?